# Problemas de tipos en typescript con useReducer TS2366

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

estoy teniendo un problema de tipo con typescript en donde al trabajar con el hook de react useReducer la consola me tira el siguiente error :

Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.  TS2366

> 5 | const Reducer = (state: InitialStateType, action: Action): InitialStateType => {

he intentado asignarle tipo al valor que devuelve el handle del submit antes de hacer las acctions, no es ese el problema parece venir vinculado a mis services o mi reducer la verdad me gustaria que pudieran guiarme...

reducerSensor.ts

```
import { InitialStateType } from "../interfaces/interfaces"
import { Action } from "../types/types";

const Reducer = (state: InitialStateType, action: Action) : InitialStateType => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'REQUEST_GET': {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            };
        }
        case 'SUCCESS_GET': {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                sensors: state.sensors.concat(action.payload)
            };
        }
        case 'ERROR_GET': {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.error,
            };
        } 
        case 'REQUEST_CREATE' : {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
            };
        }
        case 'SUCCESS_CREATE' : {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                sensors: [...state.sensors, action.payload]
            };
        }
        case 'ERROR_CREATE': {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.error,
            };
        }
    }
};

export default Reducer; `
```

ListSensor

```
import { FC ,useEffect , useReducer} from 'react'
import '../../styles/ListSensors.css'
import FormSensors from '../FormSensors/FormSensors'
import * as sensorServices from '../../services/sensorServices'
import Reducer from '../../Reducers/reducerSensor'
import { InitialStateType, Sensor } from '../../interfaces/interfaces'

const ListSensors: FC<HTMLDataListElement>= () => {

const initState: InitialStateType = {
    sensors: [],
    loading: true,
    error: false
}

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, initState )

const { sensors, loading, error } = state;

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_GET' });
    const loadSensors = async () => {
        const res = await sensorServices.getSensors();
        if (res.status === 200) {
            dispatch({ type: 'SUCCESS_GET', payload: res.data });
            return;
        }
        dispatch({ type: 'ERROR_GET', error: res.data});
    };
    loadSensors();
}, []);

const handleCreate = (objectSensor : Sensor)  => {
    dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_CREATE' });
        const createSensor = async () => {
            const res = await sensorServices.createNewSensor(objectSensor);
            if (res.status === 200) {
                dispatch({ type: 'SUCCESS_CREATE', payload: res.data });
                return;
            }
    dispatch({ type: 'ERROR_CREATE', error: res.data});
        };
   createSensor();
}

    return (
        <div>
             {loading ? (
                <p>loading...</p>
            ) : error ? (
                <p>{error}</p>
            ) : (
            <div className='datatable-container'>
                <table className="datatable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Ubication (lat / lng)</th>
                            <th>MinVal</th>
                            <th>MaxVal</th>
                            <th>Events</th>
                            <th>Options</th>         
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <FormSensors  event={handleCreate}/>     
                        {
                            sensors && sensors.length > 0 ? sensors.map((sensor: Sensor) => (
                                <tr key={sensor._id}>
                                    <td><span className={sensor.active ? "active" : "inactive"}></span></td>
                                    <td>{sensor.name}</td>
                                    <td>{sensor.ubication[0]}° lat , {sensor.ubication[1]}° lng</td>
                                    <td>{sensor.minVal}°</td>
                                    <td>{sensor.maxVal}°</td>
                                    <td><button  className="button button-event"><i className="material-icons">sensors</i></button></td>
                                    <td> <button className="button button-delete"><i className="material-icons">delete</i></button> <button className="button button-update"><i className="material-icons">edit</i></button></td>   
                                </tr>
                            )
                          )  : null
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            )}
    </div>
    )
}

export default ListSensors
```

SensorServices.ts

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Sensor } from "../interfaces/interfaces";

const API = "http://localhost:3001";

export const getSensors = async () => {
  return await axios.get(`${API}/sensors`);
};

export const createNewSensor = async (sensor: Sensor) => {
    return await axios.post(`${API}/sensor`, sensor);
  };
  
  export const deleteSensorById = async (id: string) => {
    return await axios.delete(`${API}/sensors/${id}`);
  };
  
  export const updateSensor = async (id: string, sensor: Sensor) => {
    return await axios.put(`${API}/sensors/${id}`, sensor);
  };
```

types.ts

```
import { ChangeEvent } from 'react';
import { Sensor } from '../interfaces/interfaces';

export type Action =
    { type: 'REQUEST_GET'}
|   { type: 'SUCCESS_GET', payload: Sensor }
|   { type: 'ERROR_GET' , error: string }
|   { type: 'ERROR_CREATE' , error: string }
|   { type: 'REQUEST_CREATE' }
|   { type: 'SUCCESS_CREATE', payload: Sensor }

export type InputChange = ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>;

export type SelectChange = ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement >
```

interfaces.ts

```````
export interface Sensor {
    _id?: string;
    name: string;
    ubication: number[]
    maxVal: number;
    minVal: number;
    active: boolean;
    createdAt?: string | Date;
    updatedAt?: string | Date;
  }

  export interface  SensorForm {
    name: string;
    lat: string;
    lng: string;
    active: boolean;
  }
  export interface InitialStateType  {
    sensors: Sensor[],
    loading: Boolean,
    error: Boolean | String 
  }
``````
```````

Comment: un "return state" al final faltaría

Answer (score 1):

Es porque le estas indicando que SI O SI retorne un InitialState.
Pero a esa funcion, sea el caso que le pasas un ACTION_TYPE que no corresponde con ninguna opcion del switch, te de undefined.

(Deberias ponerle un default state por ejemplo)

Yo diria que es por esto. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

El reducer debe devolver un state siempre, no solo cuando concuerda con uno de los actions, deberías agregarle un default case al switch así:

```js
default: {
  return state;
}
```